# jQuery versioning bug with checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, versioning

this simple piece of code works perfectly in jquery 1.8.3
however > jquery 1.8.3 it stops working.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(){
        if($("#stc").is(':checked'))
        {
            $("#stc").attr('checked', false);
            //do some code
        }
        else
        {
            $("#stc").attr('checked', true);
            //do some other code
            //so no toggle() I believe
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button">(de)select</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="stc">
</body>
</html>
```

try for yourself with 1.8.3:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
  if($("#stc").is(':checked')) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            //do some code
        } else {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);           
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(){
        if($("#stc").is(':checked'))
        {
            $("#stc").prop('checked', false);
            //do some code
        }
        else
        {
            $("#stc").prop('checked', true);
            //do some other code
            //so no toggle() I believe
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button">(de)select</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="stc">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

*What am I doing wrong?*

From the docs of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, **use the .prop() method.**
>
> ***Attributes vs. Properties***
>   The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.
>
> For example, selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.

I suggest you to use `.prop()` instead, you don't require to use any `if/else` condition. You just have to check the checked property of the checkbox:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#button').click(function() {
        $("#stc").prop('checked', !$("#stc")[0].checked);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">(de)select</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="stc">
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$("#stc").attr('checked', false);
```

Use `.prop()`

```
$("#stc").prop('checked', false);
```

Complete Code :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(){
        if($("#stc").is(':checked'))
        {
            $("#stc").prop('checked', false);//Or $("#stc").removeAttr('checked');
            //do some code
        }
        else
        {
            $("#stc").prop('checked', true);//Or $("#stc").attr('checked','checked');
            //do some other code
            //so no toggle() I believe
        }
    });
});
```